# Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folderPath & "\LoaderNew.xlsx") Subscript out of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy  Test.xlsx to LoaderNew.xlsx . LoaderNew has the VBA code and is open
I want copy From the last blank up to A12 across to I12 from Test.xlsx

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim myPath As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim sFile As String

folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
sFile = ActiveWorkbook.name

 Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "\Test.xlsx")

 Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folderPath & "\LoaderNew.xlsx") ----Error subscipt out of 
 range
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(aFile)
Set SourceSht = WB.Worksheets("QC SES")

LastRow = SourceSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

SourceSht.Range("A12:I" & LastRow).Copy
DestSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

END Sub
```

Comment: You are passing a file name in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(). There is no such worksheet in the workbook, hence the subscript out of range error. Between the parentheses, pass the name of a worksheet as you see it in the worksheet's tab in Excel.

Comment: That was exactly it. Sorry for such a goofy question I appreciate your help

Comment: Also when I copy I'm getting A12 and up. I want everything below A12:I12 from test.xlsx and then copy it to LoaderNew.xlsx A12:I12 and everything below

Comment: That might be because in ```SourceSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row``` ```Rows.Count``` is using the active sheet, which if it is empty will return 1. So make it ```SourceSht.Rows.Count```

Comment: No that copied blanks So I want to copy from row A12  to I12 to the bottom when the cells is empty. Then paste in A12 to I12 . Data on the source will have A12 to A45 to row populated.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a file name in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(). There is no such worksheet in the workbook, hence the subscript out of range error. Between the parentheses, pass the name of a worksheet as you see it in the worksheet's tab in Excel. – Excelosaurus 34 mins ago